# Creating fibonacci sequence generator (Beginner Python)

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to create a Fibonacci sequence generator in Python. This is my code:

```
d =raw_input("How many numbers would you like to display")

a = 1
b = 1

print a
print b

for d in range(d):
    c = a + b 
    print c
    a = b
    b = c
```

When I ran this program, I get the error:

```
File "Fibonacci Sequence Gen.py", line 10, in <module>
    for d in range(d):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str
```

Thanks for your help, I'm trying to teach myself python with basic projects.

Comment: [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C8&language=english&go=Search) says that the first fibonacci number is `0`, not `1`, [correct example](http://ideone.com/s9wGY)

Answer (score 7):

raw_input returns a string. So convert d to an integer with:

```
d = int(d)
```

One more thing: Do not use `for d in range(d)`. It works but it is awful, unpythonic, whatever.
Try this way for example:

```
numbers = raw_input("How many numbers would you like to display")

a = 1
b = 1

print a
print b

for d in range(int(numbers)):
    c = a + b 
    print c
    a = b
    b = c
```

**Edit**: I complete below the answer with additional code tuning (thanks to commenters):

```
# one space will separate better visually question and entry in console
numbers = raw_input("How many numbers would you like to display > ")    

# I personnally prefer this here, although you could put it
# as above as `range(int(numbers))` or in `int(raw_input())`
# In a robust program you should use try/except to catch wrong entries
# Note the number you enter should be > 2: you print 0,1 by default
numbers = int(numbers)  

a, b = 0, 1        # tuple assignation
                   # note fibonnaci is 0,1,1,2,3...

print a            # you can write this as print "%i\n%i" % (a, b)
print b            # but I think several prints look better in this particular case.

for d in range(numbers - 2):  # you already printed 2 numbers, now print 2 less
    c = a + b 
    print c
    a, b = b, c    # value swapping.
                   # A sorter alternative for this three lines would be:
                   # `a, b = b, a + b`
                   # `print b`
```

Comment: +1 Nice and simple... and you beat me to the punch reformatting the question by a couple seconds ;)

Comment: More pythonic would be in-place value swapping, I believe: `a, b = b, c`.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could eliminate c completely: a,b = b, a+b; print b

Comment: @ChadMiller: Ok, but of course `;` should be replaced by line break :)

Comment: @Tadeck the ; syntax that ChadMiller used is perfectly valid python. It is just not typical or desirable most of the time.  In the context of code in a comment, it is both more desirable and less surprising than adding \n's ;)

Comment: @istruble: I know it is valid Python and that you cannot insert visible line breaks in StackOverflow comments ;) I mentioned that it should be replaced (and it really should be replaced by line break in real code), because using `;` in Python code is not a good practice. As mentioned in PEP8: "_Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged._". That was the point :)

Comment: @joaquin: Your answer is incorrect also when it comes to `print a; b` - the colon means that `a` is printed, and `b` is not (it is in separate statement). Just try it within IDLE: `print 'a'; 'b'` and you will see printed "`a`" and outputted representation of string "`'b'`".

Comment: @joaquin: Also if you use `range()` only for iterating through it, the more efficient solution would be `xrange()` (especially for large `numbers`).

Comment: @joaquin: Ok, see my answer for the way I would shorten and simplify your code (your code uses 7 lines for generating Fibonacci numbers, mine uses 4). My code also separates it into a function for making it cleaner, uses generators where possible.

Comment: @Tadeck This was a **beginner** problem with strings and integers. I think we are overpowering our answers focussing on how to better code fibonnaci numbers, a problem with already well [known standard solutions](http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_(Python))

Comment: @joaquin: Yes, I agree - the problem was about incorrect type, our answers are much more than providing this information :) Anyway, good source :) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### Problem

The problem here is that here:

```
d = raw_input("How many numbers would you like to display")
```

you assign string from the input into the `d` variable, and later you pass it to `range()`. But `range()` expects expects integers, not strings, and Python does not convert it automatically (it leaves conversion to you).

### Solution

The solution is to convert result of `raw_input()` into `int` like that:

```
d = int(raw_input("How many numbers would you like to display"))
```

and everything will work unless you provide non-integer.

But there is better (shorter, more efficient, more encapsulated) method of generating Fibonacci numbers (see below).

### Better method of generating Fibonacci numbers

I believe this is the best (or nearly the best) solution:

```py
def fibo(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in xrange(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

This is a generator, not a simple function. It is very efficient, its code is short and does not print anything, but you can print its result like that:

```py
>>> for i in fibo(20):
    print i,


0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181
```

or convert it into a list like that:

```py
>>> list(fibo(20))
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181]
```

### Applying the above in your case

After applying the above to your code, it could look like this:

```py
def fibo(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in xrange(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

d = int(raw_input("How many numbers would you like to display"))
for i in fibo(d):
    print i
```

Does it answer your question?

Comment: Your function prints `n+1` numbers instead of `n`. For the most general solution you could remove `xrange()` from `fibo()` function and use `itertools.islice()`, [example](http://ideone.com/s9wGY)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You were right about `n+1` - I misunderstood the task (and returned all the numbers until the one for `n` instead of the first `n` numbers). I am not sure however, how this solution may be more general, could you explain? Also what do you think about this: http://ideone.com/DOSE9?

Comment: More general means it is applicable in a wider context e.g., `fib()` from my example may be used to generate all fibonacci numbers less than a `100000` without changing `fib()` function itself. The more general the solution at the more global scope it could be defined therefore it doesn't make sense to put a `fib()` inside `fibo()`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert the input to a number, like this:

```
d = int(raw_input("How many numbers would you like to display: "))
```

Also, just for fun, the fibonacci sequence can be expressed more succinctly:

```
a, b = 0, 1
for i in range(d):
    print a
    a, b = b, a+b
```

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input` returns string type.You need to convert it to `int`.

```
>>> x = raw_input()
2
>>> x
'2'
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
```

and `range` function requires `int` as an argument not `string`.

Thats why when i do

```
>>> range(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.
```

So, change it to

```
for x in range(int(d)):
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler method:

```
a = [0,1]
for n in range(1,41):
  a.append(a[n]+a[n-1])
  print a[-1]
```

1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
514229
832040
1346269
2178309
3524578
5702887
9227465
14930352
24157817
39088169
63245986
102334155
165580141

Answer (score 0):

I see many over complicated Fibonacci Sequence programs so I just did this with a while loop; changing the number after the while loop

`a = 0
b = 1
while a <= 1000000000: #Changing this number will change how long the sequence goes on for
    print(a)
    print(b)
    a = a+b
    b = b+a`

I know this isn't your program but it is a very basic version;
I hope this helps :)